# Calculate all the money user should pay for shopping cart

Tags: php, laravel

I have a question
I have a table called cart_product that has these fields:
qty, price, cart_id
And i have a main table called carts
So every user has one cart => carts
and every cart has a lot of products => cart_product

I wanna calculate all the money user should pay for his cart, it means i should do this for every user:
sum = qty * price

here is my models:

```
class Cart extends Model
{
    protected $with = 'coupon';
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'coupon', 'total'
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'cart_product')->withPivot(['qty', 'price']);
    }

    public function coupon()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Coupon::class);
    }
}
```

Can i do it with sum function? Thanks

Comment: Yes you can: `{your query code}->sum('price')`. [The documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#retrieving-aggregates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collections' sum function allows you to use a function as the "aggregator" (probably the wrong word) example.

The following should work:

```
$cart = Cart::with('products')->first();
$totalPrice = $cart->products->sum(function ($product) {
   return $product->pivot->price*$product->pivot->qty;
});
```

For convenience, I would add this as an attribute (though be careful if you do because it will need the products to be loaded and if they are not it will do queries, which might be expensive).

Add this in your Cart model:

```
public function getTotalPriceAttribute() {
    return $this->products->sum(function ($product) {
        return $product->pivot->price*$product->pivot->qty;
    });
}
```

The reason why this is convenient is that you can then do:

```
$totalPrice = $cart = Cart::with('products')->first()->total_price;
```

This of course works for a single cart. You can sum all the money a user must pay if they have multiple carts by doing:

```
$totalForUser = $user->carts->sum(function ($cart) {
     return $cart->total_price;
});
```

However, if you prefer to get the price via a query directly without loading the related products you can do a plain-old join:

```
    Cart::join('cart_product', 'carts.id', 'cart_product.cart_id')
         ->selectRaw('carts.*, SUM(cart_product.qty*cart_product.price) as total_cart_price')
         ->groupBy('carts.id', ...) // needs all the `carts` columns in the group by
```

This should result in each cart result to have a `$cart->cart_total_price`  with the price.

The last solution will not need to load related models so will probably be faster, but if you want to display a cart with products along with the total then use the methods above this.